# VUE JS - How to hide a div by default? And if user clicks on button then it should display using vue

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, display

Below is my complete code And here I am trying to hide the "v-show" by default. It should in hidden state by default and when the user clicks on button then it should display. I have used "display:none" css property for hiding the div default but it is not working. How can we solve this?

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.3/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button @click='toggle = !toggle'> click here </button>
  <div id="hide" v-show='toggle'>showing</div>
</div>
```

```
<script>
new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 data () {
   return {
     toggle: true
   }
 },
})
</script>
```

*css*

```
#hide {
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined `toggle: true` in component definition and you are using `v-show='toggle'` in template. But your css style always adds `display:none;` to `#hide` element.

**What does `v-show` does?**

When the condition inside the `v-show` eveluates to `false`, it will add `display: none` inline style to element and if it evaluates to `true`, it will remove the `display: none`. To be more simple, it just add and remove `display: none` from your element style. Its not adding any `display: block` or something to make your element visible.

Your element is always hidden with the CSS code you have added for `#hide` element. So even if `v-show` evaluates to true, it just removes the `display: none` inline style added. Your css code will always keeps `display: none` due to the style added for `#hide`. That means your component will always be hidden.

**Fix**

Remove the css style. Depend only on `v-show='toggle'`

**Working Fiddle.**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      toggle: false
    }
  },
})
```

```css
/* #hide {
  display:none;
} */
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.3/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button @click='toggle = !toggle'> click here </button>
  <div id="hide" v-show='toggle'>showing</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to toggle elements, this works.

```
<div>
  <div id="hide" class="btn" v-show='!toggle'>hiding</div>
  <div id="show" class="btn" v-show='toggle'>showing</div>
</div>
```